# Degree of Divergence of connected Feynman digrams

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, physics

### Background:

Consider a **connected** Feynman diagram $\Gamma$ with $E$ external lines, $I$ internal lines, $L$ loops and $V$ vertices in dimension $D \in \mathbb N$. If you are unfamiliar with the physicist's language, please consult [Diagramology by Tim Evans](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/current/qft/handouts/qftdiagramtypes.pdf) (p.1) to translate it to the language of graph theory.

Define the degree of divergence of $\Gamma$ with $L \gt 0$ as follows.

$$\Delta := DL - 2I$$

In a $\phi^N-$theory, each vertex is required to have exactly $N$ edges *locally* associated to it. For example, in the $\phi^4-$theory, we can have diagrams such as the following.

[image: Feynman Diagrams]

In the above examples, $L\gt0$ for the second and fourth diagrams (in fact, $L=1$). These diagrams are respectively *quadratically* ($\Delta = 2$) and *logarithmically* ($\Delta = 0$) divergent in $D=4$.

---

### Problem:

We would like to prove that for a $\phi^N-$theory, the degree of divergence is given by:

$$ \boxed{ \Delta = D + V \Big[n \big(\frac{D-2}{D}\big)-D \Big] - E \big(\frac{D-2}{D}\big)} \,.$$

For certain special cases, [I have verified](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344859/how-many-loops-are-there-in-a-connected-feynman-diagram-with-a-fixed-number-of-v) that this formula holds true. However, I am not sure how I should go about proving this rigorously.

Kindly help.

Comment: The counting argument to determine the superficial degree of divergence in $\phi^n$-theory is presented in [this note](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1088753.files/section12.pdf). You just need to generalize it from 4D to arbitrary dimension.

Comment: @Winther Thanks. That answers my question. Should I delete this question now or would you maybe write an answer for other readers?

Comment: I'm too lazy to do it myself, but if you want you can write up an answer yourself. If done properly then that is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Winther I wrote a summary. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each vertex comes with $N$ lines crossing at the vertex, we have $NV$ lines to start with, out of which $E$ are chosen to be external. The remaining $(NV-E)$ ones are contracted among themselves to form $I = (NV - E)/2$ internal lines. The factor of one-half is due to the fact that each contraction involves a pair of lines.

As for the number of loops, a *physical argument* based on the conservation of momentum at each vertex gives that $L=I-(V-1).$ However, as [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176463/76347) claims, this formula holds true, in general, for planar graphs and is known by the name of '*Euler-Feynman formula*'.

Plugging these equations back in the definition gives the required result.

$$ \Delta = D\Big[ \big(\frac N{2} - 1\big)V - \frac E{2} + 1 \Big] + (E-NV)\\
 \quad = D + V \Big[n \big(\frac{D-2}{D}\big)-D \Big] - E \big(\frac{D-2}{D}\big) \,.$$

---

**Source:** [Prahar Mitra, Harvard University](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1088753.files/section12.pdf) [Thanks @Winther for sharing these notes.]

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.